# Databricks Koalas fails importing parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks, spark-koalas

I ran into an error when importing parquet file from Azure data lake to databricks.
[image]

I tried other ways like importing parquet as Spark DataFrame successfully, but when I converted the Spark DF to Koalas DF, it gave the same error.

I also tried to import the data as Pandas DF successfully, but converting from Pandas DF to Koalas DF also failed.

[image]

I am new to Koalas. Can anyone shed some light on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just found that a column was named like '.*_index_.*' which caused the confusion for converting. I removed that column and it worked correctly.